# sql sparklyr sparkr dataframe conversions on databricks

Tags: r, sparkr, sparklyr, databricks

I have the sql table on the databricks created using the following code

```
%sql 
CREATE TABLE data 
USING CSV 
OPTIONS (header "true", inferSchema "true") 
LOCATION "url/data.csv"
```

The following code converts that table to sparkr and r dataframe, respectively:

```
%r
library(SparkR)
data_spark <- sql("SELECT * FROM data")
data_r_df <- as.data.frame(data_spark)
```

But I don't know how should I convert any or all of these dataframes into sparklyr dataframe to leverage parallelization of sparklyr?

Answer (score 2):

Just

```
sc <- spark_connect(...)

data_spark <- dplyr::tbl(sc, "data")
```

or

```
sc %>% spark_session() %>% invoke("sql", "SELECT * FROM data") %>% sdf_register()
```

Comment: what should go into the ... of spark_connect(...)?